# Is there a good jQuery plugin for a hide effect that looks like minimizing windows in Windows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-effects

Just as the title states, is there a jQuery plugin effect that will allow me to hide divs in a way that loos like how Windows does it? So the div would move, shrink, and become transparent to a certain point on the screen. Here is an example: http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/ This is pretty much what I'm looking for except I don't think it's possible to JUST use the effect.

Comment: google "jquery modal" or "jquery dialog"....wealth of choices

Comment: Would something like this do, then You can use jQuery UI's `scale` effect. http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/BQ8Z4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.animate()` method. What you need for the effect is to change is:

- width of the window
- height of the window
- top position
- left position

like this:

```
$('#element').animate({
    top: $(window).height(), // to force the window to minimize at the bottom corner
    left: 0,
    width: '20px',
    height: 0
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/teneff/KqTdQ/1/) with jQueryUI dialog that I've just made. And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/teneff/KqTdQ/) is without jQueryUI.

edit: You can also add transparency if you like to e.g. `opacity: 0.3`

Comment: Thanks! I discovered the animate() function right after I posted that and didn't get back in time to post the answer before you already had!