# How to create HTML5 popup with minimize etc

Tags: html, css

I am really new to HTML and CSS but have created a prototype page to get a reasonable size, look, and feel to fit on a 768x1024 or larger display.  I revised it to be used in landscape mode but it's apparent it won't fit in a typical browser window even at full screen with my minimum height and width criteria. The page doesn't contain text; just buttons, check boxes, text, and textarea "widgets".  I think that I can fiddle with sizing and make it fit into a window if there is only a top "title" bar with the minimize and close buttons but absent all the other "stuff" such as the navigation bar, tool bar, etc. found in a typical browser.

I do use a couple of web apps that are like this so I know that it is possible. I've searched Google for examples and found popups but none are like this.

My question is: how do I do this, preferably without javascript, and what is this type of window called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help with the minimizing: [Is there a good jQuery plugin for a hide effect that looks like minimizing windows in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908419/is-there-a-good-jquery-plugin-for-a-hide-effect-that-looks-like-minimizing-windo)

You're going to have to include jQuery from http://www.jquery.com and call this animate script when the window you want to minimize is clicked.

This will help you with the 'closing'.

https://api.jquery.com/hide/

When you click on an element you can call .hide() on it, effectively closing it from the user's perspective.